# Efficient way to sort two pandas columns based on a specific condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have a pandas dataframe with multiple columns (with possible None values) and I would like to order two of them in a specific manner. Let's say the dataframe is:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'YN': ['N', 'Y']*10,
                   ... ,
                   'A': [150, 5, 168, 3, 7, 145, None, 4, None, 167],
                   'B': [134, 4, 3, 123, 3, 143, 134, 2, 145, 1]})
```

Therefore something like:

```
  YN ... A    B
0  N ... 150  134
1  Y ... 5    4
2  N ... 168  3
3  Y ... 3    123
4  N ... 7    3
5  Y ... 145  143
6  N ... None 134
7  Y ... 4    2
8  N ... None 145
9  Y ... 167  1 
...
```

Then, I want to order each column such that in the rows with an N (which happens to be the even rows) we get the big numbers (let's say > 100) and in the columns with an Y we get the small numbers (let's say < 100). It is important to remark that the information is structured in pairs of 2, that is to say, the first two rows form an 'entity', then the 3 and 4 rows, and so on. Thus, if big number is in an odd position we should switch it with the correspondant small number of the same 'entity', as for example the rows 4 and 5 of column A. The None values can be considered as either big or small, it will be big if the other value of the same 'entity' is small (as in row 6 of column A) and viceversa (as in row 8 of A).

With that, the expected result should be:

```
  YN ... A    B
0  N ... 150  134
1  Y ... 5    4
2  N ... 168  123
3  Y ... 3    3
4  N ... 145  143
5  Y ... 7    3
6  N ... None 134
7  Y ... 4    2
8  N ... 167 145
9  Y ... None  1 
...
```

**Note:** the YN order is maintained throughout the entire df.

What I have thought of doing is to obtain each column as an array, order the array by iterating through it and applying some if/else conditions, and finally assign that value to the dataframe. However I don't think is the most efficient (pythonic) solution at all.

Comment: Please add your dataframes in a [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) way: it is easier to help you if we can just copy the code which creates a dataframe.

Comment: by what logic None is somtimes rfered to as a small numbers and sometimes as a big number? (are big numbers always >100 and small numbers <10?)

Comment: Okay, I think now is reproducible. The big and small numbers let's say (as edited now) that are those bigger and smaller than 100. The None can be either a small or big number BUT it has to go in the right position. Let me clarify what I mean by that with an example: take a look to the 8 and 9 rows of column A, in that case the None is not where it should be since in the 9 row we have a big number, that should actually be in row 8 (with the N value), therefore that None should be switched with the 167 of row 9. On the contrary, the None of row 6 would be in the right position.